# Retrieve login time of users among billion records

Tags: sql-server

There is a table which keeps the login information of users:

```
UserID       LoginTime               MacAddress     IPAdress
1        2017-02-05 20:02:40           --        192.168.10.3
```

This table has billion of records, we are going to get the last login time of each user with different filters, for example in 6 month ago. Also, this table should be join with Users Table for retrieving users information, also filters on Users table may be requested for example :
Where UserName='xxxx' and Last_Login_Time in  6 Month Ago, and any other filters.

I know that  there are ways like RowNumber and a way like this:

```
SELECT MAX(LoginTime) AS [Last Login Time], UserID
FROM UsersLoginHistory
GROUP BY UserID;
```

But these ways takes long time.

Can anyone suggest a better query (prefer to use offset for paging) for this issue?

Comment: What is the smallest filtering time period you are going to use?

Comment: Do you have an Index on LoginTime and Userid?

Comment: This looks like a great candidate for a columnstore index

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Why? In most of the cases you are going to filter by date. Columnstore indexes are no good when filtering is applied.

Comment: True thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

With current data model you will need to read through all table anyway to retrieve information about all users and all their last logins. To make this kind of report fast, you should pre-calculate it.

You can suggest one of the following ways:

1. Store the last login time in the UsersLogin table. Your back-end should properly update this table in the same transaction with inserting into UsersLoginHistory.
2. Create index on UserID, LoginTime.
3. You can replicate the logic of #1 somewhere in the database (using after insert trigger, for example), but i do not recommend doing this, because business logic will eventually bloat in your database.